# Heap Corruption Detected in Visual Studio, but program runs fine in another C compiler: why?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, heap-corruption

I tried searching for this problem, and couldn't find any answers.  I wrote a program that implements a stack, and its operations, with linked lists.  The program compiles and runs perfectly on a C Web IDE.

When I run the program in Visual Studio, it fails and gives me the following error:

Debug Error!
Program: C:\Users... my file path
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#78) at 0x011058C8.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

As my code runs fine elsewhere, this must be some issue with how I am using Visual Studio.  Any ideas?  I am new to Visual Studio, and am afraid this might be something stupid, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have included my code below, note that the failure is caused by the pop() function in Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* top = NULL; //initialize head

void push(int x);
void push(int x) {
    struct Node* add = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    add->data = x;
    add->next = top; //make add point to what top (head) points to (old 1st)
    top = add; //make top point to add (new 1st)
}

void pop();
void pop() {
    if (top == NULL) return;
    struct Node* temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
}

int topp();
int topp() {
    return top->data;
}

int exist();
int exist() {
    if (top->next) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void PrintIt();
void PrintIt() {
    struct Node* temp = top;
    while (temp!= NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    push(1); PrintIt();
    push(44); PrintIt();
    push(23); PrintIt();
    pop(); PrintIt();
    push(9); PrintIt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's classic symptoms of undefined behaviour (behaviour changes unexpectedly). Commonly caused by memory corruptions. `malloc(sizeof(struct Node*))` should be `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` better still `malloc(sizeof(*add))`

Comment: Per the error message: "Debug Error! Program: C:\Users... my file path HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#78) at 0x011058C8. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."  the code wrote past the end of a dynamically allocated memory buffer.  Fix that one problem and the rest should be very easy

Comment: place the function prototypes before the first function signature in the code.  When the function takes no parameters, then the prototype should have `void` between the parens, otherwise the compiler will generate code that allows any number of parameters.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for pointing that out, I actually never knew that.

Comment: the posted code calls `push()` several times and each call allocated more dynamic memory.  the call to `pop()` passes the current 'top' allocated memory pointer to `free()`  However, there are more calls to `push()` than to `pop()` so there is a memory leak when the program exits

Comment: @user3629249 Good observation, if I was going to use this for any real functionality, I would take that into consideration. My code in main was merely to test the functionality, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are doing something that is undefined behaviour (dynamic memory allocation is a real hot-bed of these issues), one of the undefined things that *may* happen is that it will work just fine.

That by no means indicates that you're doing the right thing, UB is something that should be avoided since it may act differently on another system, another compiler, or even next Tuesday at 3:05 pm :-)

---

A couple of things I *will* mention:

- you don't need all those function declarations (the prototypes) immeditely before the definitions. A definition acts as a declaration if it hasn't already been declared.
- your `exist()` function is likely to crash for an empty list since it dereferences `top`. If your intent is to detect a non-empty list, you can just use `return (top != NULL);`.
- you shouldn't explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` in C, it can cause certain subtle errors.

---

And, in fact, while looking at that last bullet point, there's your error (not specifically to do with casting, just that it's on that particular line):

```
struct Node* add = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
//                                                        ^
//                                                      oops!
```

The size of `struct Node*` is the size of a *pointer* to your structure, commonly (but not necessarily) four or eight octets. Given your actual structure has an integer *and* a pointer, that size is not going to be big enough.

It may work on *some* systems that provide a minimum dynamic memory allocation but it's definitely not advised. You should be doing:

```
struct Node *add = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                      size of the node, not pointer
```

That line has both the cast removed, and the correct size.

Comment: Hmm, that's a helpful framework to think in.  After I wrote the code, I google searched to see how others did this, and found this exact implementation in a tutorial.  Thus I am not sure how likely it is that both I, and the tutorial got it wrong, but I won't rule it out completely.

Comment: Thank you!  The concept of undefined behavior is new to me, I appreciate the explanation.  Looks like I mixed myself up with pointers again.  One question regarding your reply.  You said: "you shouldn't explicitly cast the return value of malloc in C, it can cause certain subtle errors."

Comment: Does that mean:                      struct Node* add;                      add = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)            Instead of: struct Node* add = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));

Comment: In other words, how do I NOT explicitly cast the return value of malloc?

Comment: @Joshua, initialisation of `add` (as opposed to declaration then assignment) is fine. I just meant don't do the cast immediately to the left of "malloc". My final line shows this: struct Node *add = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry for not noticing that in your reply. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No probs, @Joshua, I added a final sentence to make it clearer.